# How to implement membership based access in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure AD B2C tenant and with that i have implemented sign-in/sign-up flow in multiple applications and all are hosted.

In those applications some premium applications are restricted which means who bought some membership from our portal can only access it but the problem is whoever registered with our other applications (via AD B2C) can able to access the premium applications too.

The B2C tenant allows all users to access all applications. How to restrict some users who not having our membership from accessing premium applications?

Note:

In Azure AD, Enterprise Application option used for Role Based Authorization but i dont see equivalent option  in AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

With built-in user flows you'd probably have to do the check in the app itself. With custom policies, you could implement a validation technical profile to the login flow. But going to custom policies just for that isn't worth it in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with your first point. Lets say we have 100+ free applications and 50+ premium applications (and continuing) we cant implement this logic for all premium applications. Is there any AD B2C way for this like while registering user itself? (like own membership or not)

Comment: Oof, that would be a lot. As far as I know, with standard built-in user flows, you cannot limit user access to the apps. I'd evaluate the cost of implementing license checks in all premium apps vs implementing a custom policy/login flow that does license checks dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

As juaans mentioned, there is no direct way in built-in user flows. But there is a way which can make it easier. If the membership is stored as a custom attribute, the apps get the membership in a claim in the token. Once you have it in the token, its a very simple check in the authorization layer of the app. I am assuming app will be implementing some authorization for sure.